# Pass value to each speclj spec?

Tags: clojure, speclj

I'd like to start a service before each spec and shut it down after each spec. At the same time I want each spec to be able to use the `service` from the spec. For example (which doesn't work):

```
(describe
  "Something"

  (around [it]
          (let [service (start!)]
            (try
              (it)
              (finally
                (shutdown! service)))))

  (it "is true"
      ; Here I'd like to use the "service" that was started in the around tag
      (println service) 
      (should true))

  (it "is not false"
      (should-not false)))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a direct support for it in speclj and its internal design doesn't allow for extending it with such functionality. However, you can just use dynamic scope to achieve it:

```
(declare ^:dynamic *service*)

(describe
  "Something"

  (around [it]
    (binding [*service* (start!)]
      (try
        (it)
        (finally
          (shutdown! *service*)))))

  (it "is true"
    (println *service*) 
    (should true))

  (it "is not false"
    (should-not false)))
```

The `*service*` var will be bound to the result of `(start!)` within the `binding` scope.

Comment: BTW, it seems that is a similar example in speclj examples https://github.com/slagyr/speclj/blob/master/examples/basics/calulator_spec.clj (look at `*the-answer*` var).

Comment: Would this approach be better than just defining the service as an atom which is reset after each spec execution?

Comment: IMHO, the best option would be to support passing test fixture state to the testing function as a parameter. But as it is not possible due to the design of speclj, I would prefer using dynamic scope variable as the intention is clearer that it is meant to be set for a specified scope of a `binding` form and should not be a shared global state for use by other parts of the code.